# Odd behavior with grid, border, and anchor styling

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I consider myself to be a fairly experienced CSS user, but this problem has stumped me. I have a basic CSS setup that I would expect to work in a predictable way.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.card > div {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a class="card" href="https://example.com">
    <div>
      <p>
        Hello Stackoverflow! There is 2em of margin below me!
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note the interesting behavior where the bottom margin of the `p` appears to be `2em` instead of the following reasonable expectations

- `1em` on top, `1em` on bottom
- `0em`

This caught me off guard, so I messed with the values a bit. This is where it gets really interesting

- remove `display: grid`: `2em` on bottom drops to `0`
- remove `height: 100%`: `2em` on the bottom drops to `0`
- change `border-left` to `border`: `1em` on top, `1em` on bottom

When we remove the `a` and adjust our classes to match that (inner div becomes `.card`)

- Patterns are normal but still confusing

  - Usually `1em` on top, `1em` on bottom
- `border-left` -> `border`: changes nothing
- `height: 100%`: changes nothing
- removing `display: grid`: makes margin `0`

What the heck is going on here? The inspect tool reveals nothing, if anything it makes the issue more confusing. The `div` is offset from the anchor by `1em`, but it's not clear why

Ideally, the margin is `0` (w/o `display: grid` style), but I can settle for an even `1em` on both sides. I'm mostly curious why this behavior happens and what I can do to negate it.

Thank you wizards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wowee this *is* some strange behaviour.

It looks like the `margin-top` on the `p` is flowing out the top of the grid *but* the grid is calculating it's own height based on including that margin, so that makes it look like the `p` has a `margin-bottom` that's `2em` instead of `1em` (it's not though).

[image]

It's weird behaviour but I think it's related to the way that [margins collapse with adjacent elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

We can confirm this by adding `display: inline-block` to the `p` element (which prevents it from collapsing margins).

## Inline Block

[image: with position inline block]

So now that we know what's happening, what to do about it?

If you can live with the `display: inline-block` on the `p` then that'll work. Otherwise you could kill the margin (`p { margin: 0 }`) and replace it with padding.

## Padding instead of Margin

[image: padding instead of margin]

Comment: Thank you. While this answer does not fully explain why this happens (it gets close!) and it is still unclear if this is intentional or just a bug, it did lead me in the right direction. Future readers: I suggest messing with `.card > div > *` `display` rules. `inline-block` and `table-*` seem to have good results. For me, I ended up modifying my template to include an inner div (`<a><div><div><p>`) and applying `display: inline-block` to that div

Answer (score 0):

The first child and last child selectors can be useful for this.

For example: Removing margins

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.card > div {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.card > div :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card > div :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a class="card" href="https://example.com">
    <div>
      <p>
        Hello Stackoverflow! There is no margin below me!
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Or: Fake margins with padding

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.card > div {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

.card > div :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.card > div :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a class="card" href="https://example.com">
    <div>
      <p>
        Hello Stackoverflow! There is 1em of "margin" below me!
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```